# Add images in an array by selecting images from file chooser

Tags: java, swing

In this program, I am trying to select images from users using filechooser and then displaying those images. By default I added 2 images. When I add more images it doesn't display?

Below is my entire code

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class CLayout {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("CardLayout demo");
    JPanel panelCont = new JPanel();
    LoginView log = new LoginView();
    JPanel Img = new ImageGallery();
    CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();

    public CLayout() {       
        panelCont.setLayout(cl);
        log.setLayout(new BoxLayout(log, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        Img.setLayout(new BoxLayout(Img, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS)); 
        panelCont.add(log, "1");
        panelCont.add(Img, "2");
        cl.show(panelCont, "1");
        ActionListener loginListener = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String userName = log.getUserName();
                char[] password = log.getPassword();
                String pass=new String(password);
                if (LoginView.LOGIN.equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
                    if(userName.equals("imagegallery")&& pass.equals("12345"))
                         cl.show(panelCont, "2");
                }
           }
       };
       log.addActionListener(loginListener);
       frame.add(panelCont);
       frame.setSize(800,600);
       frame.setTitle("     Image Gallery    ");
       frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
       frame.pack();
       frame.setVisible(true);  
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
              new CLayout();
          }
      });
  }

}
class ImageGallery extends JPanel {
    private ImageIcon myImage1 = new ImageIcon ("Chrysanthemum.jpg");
    private ImageIcon myImage2 = new ImageIcon ("Desert.jpg");

    JPanel ImageGallery = new JPanel();
    private ImageIcon[] myImages =new ImageIcon[10];
    private int curImageIndex=0;
    private int count=0;
    private int total=1;
    public ImageGallery () {   
        ImageGallery.add(new JLabel (myImage1));
        myImages[0]=myImage1;
        myImages[1]=myImage2;
        add(ImageGallery, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JButton PREVIOUS = new JButton ("Previous");
        JButton NEXT = new JButton ("Next");
        JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

        JButton button = new JButton("Select File");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                int returnValue = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
                if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                    System.out.println(selectedFile.getName().toString());
                    ImageIcon tImage=new ImageIcon("selectedFile.getName().toString()");
                    System.out.println(myImages.length);
                    int n=2+count;
                    myImages[n]=tImage;
                    total=total+count+1;
                    count++;
                    System.out.println(total+"  "+count);
                }
            }
        });
        JPanel Menu = new JPanel();
        Menu.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));
        add(Menu, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        Menu.add(PREVIOUS);
        Menu.add(NEXT);
        Menu.add(button);

        //register listener
        PreviousButtonListener PreviousButton = new PreviousButtonListener ();            
        NextButtonListener NextButton = new NextButtonListener ();

        //add listeners to corresponding componenets 
        PREVIOUS.addActionListener(PreviousButton);
        NEXT.addActionListener(NextButton);
    }


class PreviousButtonListener implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(curImageIndex>0 && curImageIndex <=total) {
            ImageGallery.remove(0);
            curImageIndex=curImageIndex-1;
            ImageIcon TheImage= myImages[curImageIndex];
            ImageGallery.add(new JLabel (TheImage));
            ImageGallery.validate();
            ImageGallery.repaint(); 
        } else {   
            ImageGallery.remove(0);
            ImageGallery.add(new JLabel (myImage1));
            curImageIndex=0;
            ImageGallery.validate();
            ImageGallery.repaint();
        }
    }
}


class NextButtonListener implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if(curImageIndex>=0 && curImageIndex <total){   
            ImageGallery.remove(0);
            curImageIndex = curImageIndex + 1;
            ImageIcon TheImage= myImages[curImageIndex];
            ImageGallery.add(new JLabel (TheImage));
            ImageGallery.validate();
            ImageGallery.repaint(); 
        } else {   
            ImageGallery.remove(0);
            ImageGallery.add(new JLabel (myImages[total]));
            curImageIndex=total ;
            ImageGallery.validate();
            ImageGallery.repaint();
        }
    }
}
}
class LoginView extends JPanel {

    JLabel userLabel = new JLabel("User");
    JTextField userText = new JTextField(20);
    JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password");
    JPasswordField passwordText = new JPasswordField(20);
    private final JButton loginButton;
    private final JButton registerButton;

    public static final String LOGIN = "Login";
    public static final String REGISTER = "Regster";

    public LoginView() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));
        userLabel.setBounds(10, 10, 80, 25);
        add(userLabel);
        userText.setBounds(10, 10, 60, 25);
        add(userText);
        passwordLabel.setBounds(10, 40, 80, 25);
        add(passwordLabel);
        passwordText.setBounds(100, 40, 160, 25);
        add(passwordText);

        loginButton = new JButton("login");
        loginButton.setActionCommand(LOGIN);
        registerButton = new JButton("register");
        registerButton.setActionCommand(REGISTER);
        add(loginButton);
    }

    public void addActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
        loginButton.addActionListener(listener);
        registerButton.addActionListener(listener);
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userText.getText();
    }

    public char[] getPassword() {
        return passwordText.getPassword();
    }
}
```

Comment: did you hear about [sscce](http://sscce.org/) ?

Answer (score 3):

Problem is in this line

```
ImageIcon tImage=new ImageIcon("selectedFile.getName().toString()");
```

you need to remove double-quotes in order to read actual file name.

```
ImageIcon tImage=new ImageIcon(selectedFile.getName().toString());
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think `selectedFile.getAbsolutePath()` is more useful. I suspect `selectedFile.getName()` will return the file name only not full path